# Remote validation never gets called in Create view but it does in Edit view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit, remote-validation

I have a form in a Create View, for some reason it does not submit and hence does not call the Create controller. If I use the exact same view but for the Edit controller it works perfectly and both Create and Edit controller methods take the same parameters and they have the same attributes and they have almost the same code so I have no clue why the form in the Create view doesn´t submit but the form in the Edit view does. I think it is an error in the JQuery client side validation but no error is displayed.
I have tried everything but I'm out of ideas and I have no idea how to debug the JQuery Validation plugin to see in which field of the form it goes wrong and whether it prevents the form submit. What could make the form not submit?

This is the Create view which does not submit:

```
@model WebContingencia.Models.Contacto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear nuevo";
}

<h2>Crear</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contacto", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contacto</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celular)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celular)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celular)
        </div>        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And the model for this view:

```
public class Contacto
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Nombre demasiado largo"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar su nombre y apellido")]
        [Display(Name="Nombre y apellido")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "E-mail demasiado largo")]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [RegularExpression(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b",ErrorMessage="El e-mail no es valido")]            
        [Remote("ValidarMail", "Contacto", HttpMethod = "Post", AdditionalFields="ID",ErrorMessage = "El e-mail ingresado ya existe")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Demasiados digitos"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar su telefono celular")]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono celular")]
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }
```

And the create controller. This doesn't get called. I think the form does not even submit so I doubt it the problem is here:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(
            [Bind(Include = "ID,Nombre, Email, Celular")]
            Contacto contacto)
        {
            var record= new Record();
            record.ContactoID = contacto.ID;
            record.Operacion = "CREAR";
            record.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            record.CelCargado = contacto.Celular;
            record.EmailCargado = contacto.Email;
            contacto.Records=new List<Record>();
            contacto.Records.Add(record);
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Contactos.Add(contacto);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new DataException();
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /*dex*/)
            {
                //Uncomment dex and write here to write to log
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo guardar los cambios. Por favor intente de nuevo");
            }
            return View(contacto);
        }
```

Comment: Please also post your model and the controller methods

Comment: I found the culprit: the Remote validator in the model. If I remove it everything works. But I really need that remote validation, and for some reason it seems that adding it breaks all the jQuery client-side validation. When I add the Remote validator most calls to the jquery validation plugin do nothing.

Comment: It turns out the Remote validation never gets called on the Create view, but it does on the Edit view. Weird...

Comment: @Magnus What are you calling "remote validation"? JQuery client side validation?  Or the model validation that occurs in the controller server-side after the post?

Comment: This: `[Remote("ValidarMail", "Contacto", HttpMethod = "Post", AdditionalFields="ID",ErrorMessage = "El e-mail ingresado ya existe")]`

Comment: @Magnus As a test, temporarily remove the `AdditionalFields="ID"` and see if it hits your remote validation.  Since the create form has no ID hidden field, I suspect that is the issue.  You could add a hidden field for ID, and in your remote validation handler make that a nullable field and you can determine if the validation call is coming from the Create page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I forgot to make the id parameter in the ValidarMail function optional, so when the function was called without a parameter it couldn't find the function.

## D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller named "Contacto"?

The line `Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contacto", FormMethod.Post)` is saying to call the Create method on the Contacto controller so if your controller has a different name than your model, you need to replace this with the controller name.  This is why you should post your controller code as well as mentioned by Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Yes, the class is ContactoController.